# Cheddar Node Removal Errors

Tags: r

I've been trying to run some species deletion simulations using the cheddar package and have come across an error:

```
   Error in RemoveNodes(new.community, new.remove, title = title, method = "cascade") : 
  Removing these nodes would result in an empty community
```

you can recreate the error as such:

```
library(cheddar)
data(SkipwithPond)

a<-RemoveNodes(SkipwithPond,c('Detritus','Corixidae nymphs','Agabus / Ilybius larvae'),method='cascade')
```

i was wondering if was possible to disable this feature so as to allow the removal to occur? If not would there be a way to return a certain value (the number of nodes in the web in this case) if this error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the `cheddar` package, but the second option you mention would be to "catch" the error after trying to evaluate the expression. Enter `tryCatch`. See the documentation for this function, but generally when you save result of `tryCatch` to a variable, you can redirect your flow to accommodate for the error. Something along the lines of

```
# spaces possibly make code easier to read
a <- tryCatch(RemoveNodes(SkipwithPond, c('Detritus','Corixidae nymphs','Agabus / Ilybius larvae'), method='cascade'), error = function(e) e)
# str(a) to see what the error is (message, class...) and act on that message

# or if you want a custom message to catch  
a <- tryCatch(RemoveNodes(SkipwithPond, c('Detritus','Corixidae nymphs','Agabus / Ilybius larvae'), method='cascade'), error = function(e) "empty community?")

if (a$message == "empty community?") {
    # ...do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this it worked great with a little fiddling!